# "Finding and extracting matches with single hit" from blat output, Mac vs. linux syntax?

Tags: linux, sed, filtering, blat

Problem: the output file "single_hits.txt" is blank:

```
cut -f10 genome_v_trans.pslx | sort | uniq -c | grep '      1 ' | sed -e 's/      1 /\\\</' -e 's/$/\\\>/' > single_hits.txt
```

I have downloaded the script from Linux to be used on Mac OSX 10.7.5. There are some changes that need to be made as it is not working. I have nine "contigs" of DNA data that need to be filtered to remove all but unique contigs. blat is used to compare two datasets and output a .pslx file with these contigs, which worked:

```
964 0   0   0   0   0   3   292 +   m.1 1461    0   964 3592203 ...
501 0   0   0   0   0   3   468 -   m.1 1461    960 1461    5269699 ...
1168    0   0   0   1   2   7   1232    -   m.7292  1170    0   1170    5233270 ...
```

Then this script is supposed to remove identical contigs such as the top two (m.1)

Comment: Is there supposed to be a difference between the script at the top of the question and the one at the bottom?

Comment: You can use `uniq -u` to print just the lines that are not repeated, instead of piping to `grep`.

Comment: Make sure the fields in the `.pslx` file are separated by TABs, not spaces. That's what `cut` uses as its default field delimiter. Or you could use `awk '{print $10}'`, which will work with any kind of whitespace.

Comment: You're attempting to grab field 10, but in your description you mention both field 10 and 11 (m.1 1461).

Comment: @Barmar uniq -u does identify the matches, but just seems to remove one of the hits and not both.

Comment: I just tested it. It removes all copies of a duplicated line.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work on the limited data you gave,

```
grep -v `awk '{print $10}' genome_v_trans.pslx | uniq -d` genome_v_trans.pslx
```

unless you want it to have <> in place of the duplicates, then you can sed substitute the duplicate entries then you can do something like:

`IFS=$(echo -en "\n\b") && for a in $(awk '{print $10}' genome_v_trans.pslx | uniq -d); do sed -i "s/$a/<>/g" genome_v_trans.pslx; done && unset IFS`

results in:

964 0   0   0   0   0   3   292 +   <> 1461    0   964 3592203 ...

501 0   0   0   0   0   3   468 -   <> 1461    960 1461    5269699 ...

1168    0   0   0   1   2   7   1232    -   m.7292  1170    0   1170    5233270 ...

or if you wanted that in the singlehits file:

`IFS=$(echo -en "\n\b") && for a in $(awk '{print $10}' dna.txt | uniq -d); do sed "s/$a/<>/g" dna.txt >> singlehits.txt; done && unset IFS`

`SINGLE_TMP=/tmp/_single_tmp_$$ && awk '{if ($10 == "<>") print}' singlehits.txt > "$SINGLE_TMP" && mv "$SINGLE_TMP" singlehits.txt && unset SINGLE_TMP`

or more elegant: `sed -ni '/<>/p' singlehits.txt`

singlehits.txt:

964 0   0   0   0   0   3   292 +   <> 1461    0   964 3592203 ...

501 0   0   0   0   0   3   468 -   <> 1461    960 1461    5269699 ...